# RecursionError:maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**i'm building an e-commerece and when i try to add more than one orderitems to the order but i get this error** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWOB2.png) .
Any help is appreciated .

```
   def Cart(request):
        `enter code here`    customer=request.user.customer
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                 order,status=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)
                 items=order.orderitem_set.all()
            else:
                items=[]

            context={"items":items}
            return render(request,'store/Cart.html',context)
```

and  this the tree models

```
   class Customer(models.Model):
        user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        email=models.EmailField(null=True,help_text='A valid email address,please.') 
        objects = models.Manager() 

        def __str__(self):
            return  self.name


    class Order(models.Model):
        customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
        date_orderd=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        complete=models.BooleanField(default=True,null=True,blank=False)
        transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        objects = models.Manager() 

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.pk)

    class OrderItem(models.Model):
        product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
        order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
        quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1,null=True,blank=True)
        date_added=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        objects = models.Manager() 

        def __str__(self):
             return self.product.name

        @property
        def get_total(self):
            total=self.product.price*self.quantity
            return self.get_total
```

Comment: It means a function is calling itself, and keeps calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you add an app's urls in itself. 
check your app's url.py you mayhave included itself in it.

Comment: No i havn't include the urls of the app in the urls file .i have  saw this but is not that what  causes the problem .

Comment: please show us urls.py file of app and main project that may be helpful.

Comment: from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path("Cart/",views.Cart,name="Cart"),
    path("Checkout/",views.Chechout,name="Checkout"),
    path("",views.Store,name="Store"),
]